# MySql : InnoDB_Force_recovery = 1 leads to table in read only

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, database-performance, my.cnf

I have an application which runs under MariaDB 10.1.18 and I had problems of data corruption.
So, in my.cnf I change the parameter innoDB_force_recovery = 1 to ignore them.
But then, I can not make insert in tables. But I thought that insert are forbidden when innoDB_force_recovery = 4.
Is it possible to make insert when innoDB_force_recovery = 1 ?
Best regards.
Christophe

Answer (score 8):

**Setting `innodb_force_recovery=1` does not fix data corruption!** It *ignores* corruption to allow you to back up your data before rebuilding the database.

> Only set this variable to a value greater than 0 in an emergency situation, so that you can start InnoDB and dump your tables. As a safety measure, InnoDB prevents INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE operations when innodb_force_recovery is greater than 0.

So, no. You cannot insert data while `innodb_force_recovery` is active. Use `mysqldump` to create a backup of all data, then delete the MySQL data files and use your backup to restore it.